# Unsupported binding namespace while generating class files using xjc

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I tried googling without any help. Apologies if there are any duplicates.

I have the following schema header for the file common.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
       xmlns:meta="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/meta"
       jaxb:version="2.0"
       jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="meta"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       targetNamespace="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5"
       version="1.0">
```

I am trying to generate class files using xjc command.

```
xjc -version
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6" 
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6)
```

I am getting this error.

```
[info] [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/meta". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
[info]   line 21 of file:/Users/kcherivirala/vmware/dev/corp/zephyr/services/networkservice/app/vcd-schema/src/main/xsd/vcloud/common.xsd
```

Any leads on this would be of great help.

Comment: check this link once ..https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/unsupported-binding-namespace-perhaps-you-meant-httpjavasuncomxmlnsjaxbxjc

Comment: No it did not help. I do not have any binding xml file.

Comment: What is there on line 21 of your common.xsd file? That's where the error is so I think you should show that in your question.

Comment: how did you get this .xsd file btw - it's not the normal vcloud 1.5 common.xsd schema; that one doesn't have any jaxb: attributes on the schema.

Comment: Got the jar file of generated files which solved my issue. But still do not know the root cause.

Line 21 is "xmlns:meta="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/meta"

and about jaxb, do not know, the xsd files are already there in the repo I am using

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
   jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="meta"
```

`jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes` declares prefixes of the vendor customization namespaces. See [this link](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.11/docs/ch05.html#section-3752096477276927).

> The JAXB RI provides additional customizations that are not defined by
>   the JAXB specification. Note the following:
>
> These features may only be used when the JAXB XJC binding compiler is
>   run in the -extension mode.
>
> All of the JAXB RI vendor extensions are defined in the
>   "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" namespace.
>
> The namespaces containing extension binding declarations are specified
>   to a JAXB processor by the occurrence of the global attribute
>   @jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes within an instance of 
>   element. The value of this attribute is a whitespace-separated list of
>   namespace prefixes. For more information, please refer to section
>   6.1.1 of the JAXB Specification.

You only need this when you customize the binding. For instance you may use `xjc:superClass` to customize to extend a common super class. In this case, `xjc` would be in `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes`.

If you just compile your schema, the prefix of your schema will most definitely NOT be in `jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes`. So, XJC just complained it was there but was not a binding extension.